# Removing Value Proposition from Registration Form

Tags: registration, simplicity, value

Are there any sources out there that shows the benefits in removing the value proposition from registration. I remember reading an article a while back about this, but can't remember the source.

I started noticing that most websites rely on the landing page to state out the value proposition and leave the registration forms to be as simple and straight forward as possible. Any real data or studies would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Just for context, I'm trying to convince a co-worker in simplifying the registration form for our company's website.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean keeping a value proposition on (or leaving it out of) CTA, there's a great demonstration offered by GoodUI: http://goodui.org/#18
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value proposition is what will make the user want to register. I've never really seen a registration form that had it's value proposition inside the registration form or on the same page as the registration form when the registration form is on a different page.

People need to be coaxed towards the registration form, they need to be trigger. You do that by showing your value proposition on the landing page. It increases the conversion rate.

People won't press the newsletter subscribe button when they don't know they can get awesome deals and telling them when they are about to enter their email address is a little too late.

As for keeping forms as simple as possible: it all comes down to privacy and speed. People don't want to spend a lot of time registering for something and they especially don't want to enter data they'll doubt you'll have any use of. Don't ask for phone numbers when communication can mostly be done by email. Stuff like that.

Comment: I agree with your statement, but I was specifically looking for sources that can demonstrate this. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/06/fundamental-guidelines-of-e-commerce-checkout-design/) has some pointers. [Designmodo](http://designmodo.com/ux-sign-up-form/) has some pointers too, even one about continuing selling the product on the registration page.

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat the value in the registration form, at least on the header and CTA button i.e.

Join now
Sign up for free
Sign up to [drive]
Start riding with Uber
Get Started
Give [Prezi] a try
Claim Your Free Trial

Check out [Ultimate Guide How to Optimize Registration Form for Higher Conversion](https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-optimize-registration-form-conversion-rate)